Best PCB design techniques regarding signals in micro/nano amps?
I have a design where I am measuring square waves of currents in the order of microamps, specifically 100nA to 200uA (trace 1). I also have a triangle wave on the same board running at 1kHz, 10Vp-p (trace 2) the outputs about 2mA through a capacitor. I have these traces separated but I'm interested in reducing the amount of cross talk as much as possible.
I essentially have this board below where W1 is the width of trace 1, L1 is the length of trace 1, G1 is the distance from trace 1 to the ground plane, and the same for trace 2. G is the width of the ground plane for completeness.

The major issue is that I'm not sure how to handle the grounding for such a signal. If I place ground next to/below the trace, then I will have higher capacitive coupling to ground and much of the current will be shunted away from my measurement point, decreasing the accuracy of the measurement.
However, If I keep ground away from trace 1, then it's electric field can fray into all directions and can easily have other signals couple onto it including trace 2.
I also am interested to know if can abuse the 3W rule? Reduce the width of trace 1 (W1) so that by the 3W rule, I can reduce the cross talk of the board further, or is going to the minimum trace width would be a bad idea. I would not expect a large voltage drop over the trace since its passing such low currents.
Is there a rule of thumb or methodology to determine the best practice in such a scenario?

What are the signals from? Where are they going? What is the impedance? Voltage? What orientation is the figure (PCB cross section? top-down? what about other layers?)? Are there nearby/ambient noise sources to be concerned about, or emissions likewise?

Can you send this signal around deferentially? Or perhaps use an active guard trace?

Are you familiar with the idea of a guard ring?

What frequency is the square wave?
